# Should I ask the Editor for a third Referee when the answer of first two Referees do not agree?

Tags: peer-review, paper-submission, editors, physics

I submitted a theoretical paper to Physical Review Letters, and the editor answered that it can be published in Physical Review but it seems not suitable for a Letter given the Referee responses. 
Basically, one of the Referee recommends a Letter, while the other recommends a normal Physical Review.

I would like to answer the editor/referee, in order to try to get published as a Letter. What is the best things to do in this situation? Of course, in any case, we should answer all the comments and try to convince the Referee. But is it useful to ask the editor for a third Referee in this case? Is it really hopeless to try to convince the Referee? Will be the third Referee a kind of a lottery?

More details about the specific situation:

One of the Referee praises our work for the interesting results, and for the clarity and readability of the manuscript. Also they say that it would stimulate new experiments, and recommend the publication as a Letter, after some minor points are addressed.

The other Referee however has a different opinion. They say that it is difficult to understand, cumbersome, and even raises a fundamental problem about our main result, which in their opinion is in contrast with the existing literature. Also, they say that the measure proposed will not stimulate the experimental community, since that, in their opinion, the measure seems not easy and there is no qualitative advantage in this proposal, compared with other methods.

Now, I and the other coauthors have fixed the manuscript, and we are able to show that our results do not contradict existing literature, and that the measure is possible (a very similar measure has been already done). I should remark that the topic of our manuscript is a phenomenon which has been confirmed very recently in 2 papers using the same experimental technique. Our proposal refers to a different signature of the same phenomenon.

EDIT: I don't want to appeal, since I think that the Refereeing process has been fair, at least so far. Appealing should be reserved only in the case that one has the impression that the Refereeing was kind of unfair, biased, or fundamentally wrong.

Comment: May advice.  If the paper was rejected, go to another journal.  Do not make further attempts at that journal.

Comment: I'm facing a similar situation and would really love to find out what happened in your case!

Answer (score 3):

The situation you are describing is not uncommon at all. Acceptance of an article in the prestigious [Physical Review Letters](http://journals.aps.org/prl/authors/editorial-policies-practices) *is* a big deal, and that is also the popular perception regarding it, primarily because of the high reviewing standards. Having personally attended a talk about this issue from one of the journal editors, I point out the technical correctness of work is not sufficient to guarantee publication in PRL - how much captivating is it for the Physics community is also a big factor. (Some part of this is hinted at, in the [*Acceptance Criteria* of the journal](http://journals.aps.org/prl/authors/editorial-policies-practices).) Unless both the referees strongly recommend that the article qualifies to be a PRL on all eligibility counts, the decision is generally unfavorable. It is important to note that not all articles rejected by the journal are necessarily incorrect - some can rejected only because they were not deemed to be interesting enough!

In your situation, you can definitely *appeal*. This has been treated in the journal's [Editorial Policies and Practices](http://journals.aps.org/prl/authors/editorial-policies-practices), under a separate tab of **[Appeals](http://journals.aps.org/prl/authors/editorial-policies-practices#appeals)**, from where I quote:

> Authors may appeal a rejection of their paper by the editors. In the case of a formal appeal, the paper and all relevant information, including the identities of the referees, will be sent to a Divisional Associate Editor (DAE). The DAE may review the case on the existing record or may seek additional expert opinion. The DAE will present an advisory opinion to the editors, which will be sent to authors and/or referees with the DAE's name.
>
> Authors may suggest those DAEs they feel are appropriate (or not appropriate) to conduct the review, but the editors are not bound by such suggestions. If there is no suitable DAE available, the editors may appoint an appropriate scientist to consider a paper under appeal as an ad hoc DAE.
>
> The author of a paper that has been rejected subsequent to a DAE review may request that the case be reviewed by the Editor in Chief of the American Physical Society. This request should be addressed to the Editors, who will review the file and, if appropriate, forward the entire file to the Editor in Chief. Such appeals must be based on the fairness of the procedures followed, and must not be a request for another scientific review. The questions to be answered in this review are: Were our procedures followed appropriately and did the paper receive a fair hearing? A decision by the Editor in Chief is the final level of review.

Please note that the above form of *appeal* is more of a fairness measure from the point of view of the journal - just in case the authors feel they haven't got a fair review. You must note that the official statement here is "*In the case of a formal appeal, the paper and all relevant information, including the identities of the referees, will be sent to a DAE*". So, the report by the second referee (as well as info as to who this guy is) shall also be sent to the DAE. Thus, he can also uphold the second referee's verdict if he considers it appropriate, i.e. if the reasons appear genuine. But, of course, he may also rule otherwise.

Quite obviously, this *appealing* does not guarantee that the paper makes the cut in the journal, it is only like a half shot more at it. It may also happen that the DAE may not feel that it makes a very strong case for a letter, even though there may not be any fundamental flaw with the results. If that happens, and even otherwise, don't feel very bad about missing out on a PRL. It is much more important that the contents of the article are correct, and the *Rapid Communications* section of Physical Review A/B/C/D/E might be a safe bet too. And of course, you can always opt for other letter journals. But if you think it makes a strong case, PRL does offer you a procedure for *appealing* too. Avail it if you wish.

Comment: I was thinking to just resubmit the paper. What is the advantage to appeal instead of simply resubmit? (I don't even know if it is possible at this stage to appeal)

Comment: Also, I don't think that the Review process was not fair or fundamentally flawed, in order to justify an appeal. I think that some of the Referee criticism was justified, and surely useful to improve the paper. I think that they were not able to see the potentiality of the paper beyond that criticism.

Comment: @sintetico - 1. I'm not sure about the _simply resubmit_ option. I have no experience in that territory, but when I submit an article to a journal, I'm asked to certify that the manuscript is not in consideration anywhere else. Now, of course, a manuscript that they turned down is also _not in consideration_, but I'm not sure if it is not problematic to submit what is essentially only the _turned down_ manuscript once again, and hope that you get a different set of referees this time around. The journal people will most probably get this information out from their records. So, I'm not sure.

Comment: @sintetico - 2. Since you agree that the referee response was beneficial, one option can be to _revise_ your manuscript after adapting it in accordance with the referee's criticisms, and including how "_(y)our results do not contradict existing literature_" etc. But if the referee wanted this route to be taken, he could've put that part in his report. One ref (not of PRL though) once did that to an article of mine - "_I have these concerns_ ... _if you resubmit, address these explicitly_ ..._not possible in the present form_". But in your case, if ref didn't say that, possibly your (contd.)

Comment: (contd.) diagnosis of the referee not being "_able to see the potentiality of the paper beyond that criticism_" is true. In that case, this revise and resubmit option may not even exist. To be sure, you can ask the editor of the journal. :)

Comment: Ok maybe there is a misunderstanding here. I do not want to submit the paper to another journal. Also, the state of the paper is "with author" (so it is under consideration) and the possible options are "respond to editor/referees" and "transfer to another APS journal". Sorry, when I used the word "resubmit" I really mean "respond to editor/referee".

Comment: @sintetico - Oh, in that case, it is best to take the route of "_respond to editor/referees_". In that case, you can explicitly ask them whether you should _revise and resubmit_ !

Comment: Yes ok, but then you still have to answer my question....should I ask the Referee for a third Referee or just address the issues of the bad review and try to convince the reviewer? Your answer at the present stage does not answer my question, but another.

Comment: @sintetico - IMO, routemap: 1. Address the issues and try to convince, 2. (if 1. doesn't work) Appeal and seek DAE intervention, which is perhaps the PRL equivalent of third referee, 3. (if both don't work) take the option of switching from PRL to something else. But (1) should be the only option at this stage. That's in my opinion. :)

Comment: Ok, let us focus on the first step of your routemap. The question is about which one of these 2 options is better:
1 - Answer to referee/editor addressing the issues and trying to convince

OR

2 - the same, but suggesting to the editor to contact a 3rd referee. This is of course possible in PRL.

Answer (score 1):

Space is so competitive in top journals that they often take *any* bad review as sufficient cause to filter out one of their many submissions.  You are unlikely to persuade the editor unless you can show a real problem with the bad review.  I recently convinced an editor to look again at a rejected paper by revising it along the lines of the positive review and then resubmitting it.  The paper got rejected again, but we needed to do the revision before submitting to another journal anyway, and I was impressed the editor at least reconsidered their decision.